# Не получается добавить изображение в окно Python

Tags: python, изображения, turtle

Не получается добавить изображение в окно Python
Вот код:

```
from turtle import *

def test():
    speed(1) # set the slowest speed to see the turtle movements
    bgpic('бугатти.png')
    fd(100)
    goto(50, 100)
    mainloop()

test()
```

Comment: Попробуйте bgpic поставить перед вызовом функции test.

Comment: Не получается, выдаёт ошибку:

Comment: У меня ваш код работает. Картинка находиться в той же директории, что и скрипт?

Comment: В смысле ? Я например программирую в PyCharm, и чтоб код сработал, надо картинку в приложение загрузить ?

Comment: Если вы просто обращаетесь по имени файла png, то он должен размещаться рядышком с файлом .py,  иначе используйте полный путь к файлу r’ C:….png’.

Comment: Вот можете почитать о путях https://www.google.com/amp/s/highload.today/luchshaya-praktika-rabota-s-putyami-i-fajlami-v-python/amp/